# How can I assign a JS function to a list of tag that are generate with a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, twig

I have a loop in my twig file :

```
{% for item in listItem %}
<h2 class="title" id="name-id"> ID {{ item.getRobotName() }}</h2>
<p id="latbot" data-lat="lat">{{ item.geteLat() }}</p>
<p id="lonbot" data-lon="lon">{{ item.getLon() }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

In my Javascript file I have:

```
let h2 = document.getElementById("name-id");
        h2.addEventListener("click", link);


        function link() {

            document.getElementById("name-id");
            
            
            let thisLat = document.getElementById('latbot').getAttribute('data-lat');
            console.log(thisLat);

            let thisLon = document.getElementById('lonbot').getAttribute('data-lon')
            console.log(thisLon);

            let notifyIcon = L.divIcon({
                className: 'notify-icon',
                iconSize: [25, 25],
                html: '<span></span>'
            });

            map.panTo([thisLat, thisLon]);
            L.marker([thisLat,thisLon], {icon: notifyIcon}).addTo(map);
        }

        linkToMarker();
```

I would like to assign a JS function to all the h2 that are generate with this for loop. How can I do that ?

Only the first item is connected to the JS function but not the others

Thank you.

Comment: what you mean with "assign a js function"?

Comment: The h2 tag is link to an addEventListener in my JS file. let h2 = document.getElementById("idbot");
        h2.addEventListener("click", linkToMarker);

Comment: Create unique id's or use classes

Comment: What do you mean by unique ids ?

Comment: I just edited my post with my JS function

Comment: id's have to be unique, what you are doing with the loop is creating the same id X times

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags - how is this question related to PHP or Twig themself?

Comment: I didn't notice that. That's mean I need to review my loop and change it so that the generated h2 tag are proper to their own data

Comment: @NicoHaase Ok, I'm sorry. I still don't know how to post well on this forum